# How to create a global state in react with useContext, useHook and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to create a global state using a combination of useState with useContext in react using typescript.

```
#store.tsx

export const StoreContext = React.createContext();

export const StoreProvider = (({ children }: ChildrenType) => {
  const [test] = React.useState(['world']);

  const store = {
    test,
  };

  return <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>;
});
```

```
#app.tsx

import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { StoreProvider } from '../store';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <StoreProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </StoreProvider>
  )
}
```

```
#index.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { StoreContext } from '../store';

export default function Home() {
  const { test: [test] } = React.useContext(StoreContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        hello
        {test}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now this works fine when I run in development mode (in this case `npm run dev`) however when I try and build it I get the following error:

```bash
$npm run build

> state-poc@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Linting and checking validity of types .Failed to compile.

./pages/index.tsx:7:11
Type error: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

   5 |
   6 | export default function Home() {
>  7 |   const { test: [test] } = React.useContext(StoreContext);
     |           ^
   8 |
   9 |   return (
  10 |     <div0
```

I have created a POC that contains this example here: https://github.com/jamesla/state-poc

How can I make this work?

Comment: This is a type error. There is no type information on the context. Try useContext<ISomeInterface>(initialState);

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned a `type` to your context nor you have provided a value `createContext()`. So, typescript doesn't know what type the context will be. By default, it will be `unknown`.

You need to give a type to your context. You can do it like the following if it is going to be a string array and also pass the default value, if you want to avoid null checks.

```
export const StoreContext = createContext<Array<string>>([])
```

I recommend you to check out [this blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) so that you don't have to re-invent any patterns.

Also, if you plan to use context as a global state, remember that it is not ideal for state that changes frequently. You should check out [making react context fast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKlXqrcBx88), which is another pattern to improve the performance.

Comment: Hmm i've tried this `export const StoreContext = createContext<Array<string>>([])
` and it does the same thing

Comment: I think the problem is related to this line `const { test: [test] } = React.useContext(StoreContext);` since the key test or array value test doesn't necessarily exist?

Comment: Since the context is an array, instead of passing store object `value={store}`, you should pass the array itself, like this: `value={test}` and your `useContext` would look like this: `const context = React.useContext(StoreContext)` and `context[0]` will be `world`